# MATLAB for loop for 3 conditions with the same variable "speed"

Tags: matlab

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to do this code but nothing seems to be working. Could someone please show how to write the code for this equation

[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck at? You can create a loop with if conditions to separate between speed formulas.

Comment: If you post the code you tried and didn't work, we can give more meaningful pointers and advice. Right now the question looks like "please do my homework for me".

Answer (score 1):

```
index=0;
time_axis=0:0.1:25; %i chose time step as 0.1 seconds
speed=zeros(1, numel(time_axis)); %this line is for memory allocation, its optional
for t=0:0.1:25 %we could also use a while loop on time_axis elements
index=index+1; 
if t<5
speed(index)= 0.1553567*t^6-2.0416*t^5 ... %complete the formula
elseif t<15.4
speed(index)=0.0039.... %complete the formula
else
speed(index)=.... %complete the formula
end

end
plot(time_axis,speed); %you can use xlabel, ylabel and title functions to write labels
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`heaviside`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html) function, and create an function handle by combining the individual equations at the specified domains.

```
eq1 = @(t) t.^6 + t.^5;     % etc.
eq2 = @(t) t.^5 + t.^4;     % etc.
eq3 = @(t) t.^2 + t;        % etc.

f = @(t) eq1(t) + heaviside(t-5).*(eq2(t)-eq1(t)) + heaviside(t-15.4).*(eq3(t)-eq2(t));

t = 0:25;

y = f(t);
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use Heaviside when I can just write a logical comparison, like t<5?